# Overlap method for Hotel Reservation system Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am refactoring code for a hotel reservation system, specifically a method to list all the vacancies in the hotel, for a school project. Our instructor provided his solution and unfortunately he and the rest of our school is on break until Monday (when our refactoring assignment is due). StackOverflow, I could utilize your help.

Essentially, my question boils down to why was bang (!) used in the following code.

```
def overlap?(other)
  return !(other.checkout <= @checkin || other.checkin >= @checkout)
end
```

This code is a method within Module Hotel and class DateRange. It is called in another class to check for vacancies for a given date range, see below.

```
overlap_reservations = @reservations.select do |res|
    res.overlaps(dates)
end
```

In my mind, I would have not utilized bang. But I am a newbie and am blind to the interplay here. Any help you can provide is appreciated.

Comment: In this context, `!` means `not`. In other words, if the code within the parentheses evaluates to `true`, the method will return `false`, and if the code within the parentheses evaluates to `false`, the method will return `true`. The second method you provided does not call `overlap?`, it calls `overlaps`, which would be a different method altogether.

Comment: Thanks @moveson. I made a mistake typing the method overlap? it was supposed to be overlaps.

Answer (score 1):

This code suffers several severe code smells/glitches, that should never appear in the good ruby code.

```
def overlap?(other)
  return !(other.checkout <= @checkin || other.checkin >= @checkout)
end
```

1. one should never use explicit `return` in the last line of ruby method. Ruby will return the value, the last line was evaluated to, automatically.
2. one should try to simplify the conditions as possible, since the human brain is vulnerable to double/triple conditions with negations.
3. one should not mix `!` negation with a disjunction, since it is expanded  to a conjunction.
4. I doubt the code above is even correct, if we are talking about commonly used “checkins” and “checkouts.”

The summing up:

```
def overlap?(other)
  # boolean for whether other checkout overlaps
  co = other.checkout >= @checkin && other.checkout <= @checkout
  # boolean for whether other checkin overlaps
  ci = other.checkin >= @checkin && other.checkin <= @checkout
  # return a result
  ci || co
end
```

or, using the whole power of ruby:

```
def overlap?(other)
  ci_co_range = @checkin..@checkout
  ci_co_range.cover?(other.checkout) || ci_co_range.cover?(other.checkin)
end
```

or (from your forthcoming Christmas lesson :)

```
def overlap?(other)
  [other.checkout, other.checkin].any? do |co_ci|
    (@checkin..@checkout).cover?(co_ci)
  end
end
```

Documentation: [`Range`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html), [`Enumerable#any?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F).

Comment: thanks for your insights. You've given me a lot to research and think about!